# ANDROID: How to put an image on the bottom third of a button

Tags: java, android, image, button

I am trying to make a small game that has different levels. For each level, if you beat it you will be awarded a number of stars. How should I display these stars at the bottom on the level?

If the level has not been completed, no stars would appear, but if the level was completed I want to add an image (one with one star, one with two, and one with three) to the bottom of my level # button.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: What have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog by Goran Siric. It is a little old but it has really good examples of different kinds of compound buttons and you should be able to customize to your needs.

http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/8/Creating-Android-button-with-image-and-text-using-relative-layout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

/*remember to first clear the callback of the drawable you are replacing to prevent memory leaks...
* Get the Drawables for the button by calling: myButton.getCompoundDrawables(), then loop through that calling myOldDrawable.setCallback(null);
* e.g:*/

```
for(Drawable myOldDrawable : myButton.getCompoundDrawables())
{
  myOldDrawable.setCallback(null);
}
```

//use null where you don't want a drawable

```
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null, myNewDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may draw all three stars below levels and switch the visibility of each star from GONE to visible according to your need, rather than creating images at run each time.
if user got three stars make all of them visible, if he got two stars make first two visible and thirdone GONE.
you can do it like this.

```
ImageView iv;
//initialize iv according to your method or you may initiaze it directly from 
//xml.
iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//or 
iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```